# Batch file to move a number of files, then replace each of them with one file of another type while letting them keep their original name

Tags: batch-file, replace, file-rename

First off I want to say that

-I didnt ever create a batch file yet, but I am really willing to learn

-I am not even sure if what i want to do is possible with a batch file

What i want to do is the following:

I want to replace a number of files of one file type in a folder each with one and the same file of another file type. In doing this, i want the "replaced" files to keep their original name except for the "replacer" file's extension. I am not talking about file conversion, this is about replacing several different files each with one and the same file, so each of them will look the same later, just with different names and the file extension of the "replacer" file. All of the files inside the folder are to be treated this way, there are no exceptions.
So it looks something like this:

```
        Folder 1                    Folder 2
       10000000.tga------------->10000000.png (looks like replacer.png)
       10000001.tga------------->10000001.png (looks like replacer.png)
       10000011.tga------------->10000011.png (looks like replacer.png)
```

I really hope that my description is sufficiently precise, if not so, I am of course willing to give any information needed. I found parts of what i need (e.g. a loop for files in a folder, an order to replace one file with another file) but I am unsure of how to combine them at all, let alone to achieve what I actually wanted to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: what's the question? How to do this? Windows or Unix / Linux?

Comment: So you are trying to rename the files in some folder to replace their extensions with the extension of the file named "replacer" (in your example)? Is replacer.png in the same folder as the other files? Will all the files to rename have the same extension?

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%i in (*.tga) do (
  copy "replacer.png" "%%~ni.png"
  del "%%i"
)
```

see `for /?` for details about the `%%~..` syntax